# How to use standardized residuals from garch for diagnostics ? and then use AIC and BIC criterion

Tags: r, time-series, garch, arch

**1) i would like to do diagnostics test on the standardized residuals but i'm not sure how to use them, neither how to get them for example in R:

**2 ) After the fitting i would like also to compare my garch-models using the AIC and BIC criterion, how can i do that ?**

I'm using R and i'm stuck with these doubts; i also tried :

```
z = residuals(fit)/sigma(fit)
```

a then do my diagnostics using z, is this correct ?

In one example i saw

```
acf( x = fit1@fit$z, lag.max = )
```

but i don't know what does the following command mean

```
fit1@fit$z
```

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here, but
you may have a real statistical question buried here. 
You may want to edit your question to clarify the underlying 
statistical issue. You may find that when you understand 
the statistical concepts involved, the software-specific elements are 
self-evident or at least easy to get from the documentation.

Comment: I saw many questions about how R functions work and about their output meaning, that's why i didn't thought it was off-topic. Anyway thank you, i'll continue to read the documentation

Comment: It's a subtle & tricky distinction. It's fine to have a question that's partly about software in various ways, but the question needs to be about statistics at its core, not 'what is the function / package for this'. I think your question can be made on topic rather easily, if you want to. Just ask about how to get standardized residuals from a GARCH, how to use those for diagnostic tests, & how to compare the models w/ AIC / BIC. You can also state that you are using R, & illustrate your situation w/ R, just don't be asking for an R function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to just do diagnostics in R, it is quite easy with fGarch package.

```
model1=garchFit(~arma(1,1)+garch(1,1),data=data)
summary(model1)
```

Summary gives you Standardised Residuals Tests.
If you want to do other test you can get standardized residuals with:

```
residuals(model1, standardize = T)
```

Other information can be found here:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fGarch/fGarch.pdf

I think that the same principle works also for rugarch package.

Comment: thank you, 'residuals(model1, standardize = T)' and 'residuals(fit)/sigma(fit)' they both give the same output

Comment: @sonnyfamous, note that the tests' null distributions (and thus the critical values and the p-values) differ depending on whether the tests are applied on raw data or model residuals. Therefore, you cannot simply take the model residuals, apply, say, a Ljung-Box test or an ARCH-LM test and use the regular critical and p-values. The results will be misleading then. The model diagnostics that come from the model output (like `summary(model1)`) hopefully account for that and can hopefully be trusted.

Comment: @ richard hardy my intention was to apply a Ljung-Box test and an ARCH test using   'fit1@fit$z'  where        'fit1 = ugarchfit (...)' .   Could you give a brief explanation ? thank you